# Importing data using R from SQL Server truncate leading zeros

Tags: sql, r, sql-server, data.table, leading-zero

I'm trying to import data from a table in SQL Server and then write it into a `.txt` file. I'm doing it in the following way. However when I do that all numbers having leading 0 s seems to get trimmed.

For example if I have `000124` in the database, it's shown as `124` in the `.txt` as well as if I check x_1 it's 124 in there as well.

How can I avoid this? I want to keep the leading 0 s in x_1 and also need them in the output .txt file.

```
library(RODBC)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

cn_1 <- odbcConnect('channel_name')
qry <- "
select
    *
from table_name
"
x_1 <- sqlQuery(channel=cn_1, query=qry, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rm(qry)
setDT(x_1)
fwrite(x=x_1, file=paste0(export_location, "file_name", date_today, ".txt"), sep="|", quote=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, na="")
```

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeros... only strings do. You need to ensure you treat it as a string at all points to keep zeros.

Comment: @DaleK yeah.. I want to consider those fields as strings. How can I make sure that I do so. Where should I change in the code. that's what I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the underlying data in the DBMS is indeed "string"-like ...

`RODBC::sqlQuery` has the `as.is=` argument that can prevent it from trying to convert values. The default is `FALSE`, and when false and not a clear type like `"date"` or `"timestamp"`, RODBC calls `type.convert` which will see the number-like field and convert it to integers or numbers.

Try:

```r
x_1 <- sqlQuery(channel=cn_1, query=qry, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
```

and that will stop auto-conversion of all columns.

That is a bit nuclear, to be honest, and will stop conversion of dates/times, and perhaps other columns that *should* be converted. We can narrow this down; `?sqlQuery` says that `read.table`'s documentation on `as.is` is relevant, and it says:

```
   as.is: controls conversion of character variables (insofar as they
          are not converted to logical, numeric or complex) to factors,
          if not otherwise specified by 'colClasses'.  Its value is
          either a vector of logicals (values are recycled if
          necessary), or a vector of numeric or character indices which
          specify which columns should not be converted to factors.
```

so if you know which column (by name or column index) is being unnecessarily converted, then you can include it directly. Perhaps

```r
## by column name
x_1 <- sqlQuery(channel=cn_1, query=qry, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.is = "somename")

## or by column index
x_1 <- sqlQuery(channel=cn_1, query=qry, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.is = 7)
```

(Side note: while I use `select * ...` on occasion as well, the presumption of knowing columns by-number is predicated on know all of the columns included in that table/query. If anything changes, perhaps it's actually a SQL view and somebody updates it ... or if somebody changes the order of columns, than your assumptions of column indices is a little fragile. All of my "production" queries in my internal packages have all columns spelled out, no use of `select *`. I *have* been bitten once when I used it, which is why I'm a little defensive about it.)

If you *don't know*, a hastily-dynamic way (that double-taps the query, unfortunately) could be something like

```r
qry10 <- "
select
    *
from table_name
limit 10"
x_1 <- sqlQuery(channel=cn_1, query=qry10, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.is = TRUE)
leadzero <- sapply(x_1, function(z) all(grepl("^0+[1-9]", z)))
x_1 <- sqlQuery(channel=cn_1, query=qry, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.is = which(leadzero))
```

<sup>*Caveat: I don't use `RODBC` nor have I set up a temporary database with appropriately-fashioned values, so this untested.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Let `x_1` be the result data.table from your SQL query. Then you can convert numeric columns (e.g. `value`) to formatted strings using `sprintf` to get leading zeros:

```r
library(data.table)

x_1 <- data.table(value = c(1,12,123,1234))
x_1
#>    value
#> 1:     1
#> 2:    12
#> 3:   123
#> 4:  1234

x_1$value <- x_1$value |> sprintf(fmt = "%04d")
x_1
#>    value
#> 1:  0001
#> 2:  0012
#> 3:  0123
#> 4:  1234
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>